# How to fix: "Database Cant be imported" in C# using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm making a program for a C# project using Visual studio, and whenever I tried to insert the data into the database, it succeeded. But whenever I tried to refresh the db, it gives "The Database cannot be Imported. It's either an Unsupported SQL Server Version or an unsupported database compatibility" error.

The form i used is Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) and the database is SQL Server Database Project

Tried changing the Copy to Output directory to copy if newer, didn't work.

The code to save the input in registration form

```
using (DatabaseProjectEntities db = new DatabaseProjectEntities())
{
    db.MsUser.Add(usertemp);// msuser is name of the table &                          
                            // usertemp type is MsUser
    db.SaveChanges(); // saves

    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    this.Close(); // form closes
}
```

After I used the registration form, it shows MessageBox "Success!".

It saves into the current running program, but when I tried to refresh the database, it shows the error.

But when I tried to login in login form

```
using (DatabaseProjectEntities db = new DatabaseProjectEntities())
{

    var peperesult = (...
        // selecting required data
        }
    );
...
//if else statement checking data is available in the database or not
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
        this.Close();
    }
```

It shows "Login success", meaning the data already inserted.

If I close the running program, the data doesn't get inserted.

Update #1, I managed to make it work by simply use the database in bin/debug, however, since i have to submit it to other person, i have to use the database inside the project instead of using the visual studio one.

Comment: It is unlikely that the error message is literally "Database cant be implemented", since that's not even grammatically correct, and I know Microsoft does a better job proof reading than that. Please include the actual text of the exception, as text, in your question. Please also include what template you used to create your project.

Comment: my bad, i'm kinda off with searching for the answer and didnt double check it. it was "The Database cannot be Imported. It's either an Unsupported  SQL Server Version or an unsupported database compability."

Comment: The form i used is Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)
and the database is SQL Server Database Project

Comment: I'm guessing you already found this and it didn't help you? : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/3b946dbf-c8d2-4c5b-ba0c-82ec8996bc99/visual-studio-this-database-cannot-be-imported?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: yup! it's at Copy if Newer behaviour, didnt work

Comment: A SQL Server Database Project is not a database. I think you have localdb as database which is a notorious source of confusion as to where the database files are situated and overwritten. Use Sql Server Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, When my colleague made the first part of the project, he used an outdated Visual Studio to make it. Creating an older version of the Database.

After using the same version of Visual Studio. Change the Database behavior to Copy If Newer. It doesn't have any problem at all.

Guess next time I'm going to make sure we are all using the same version. :/